# Coroutine await() function not waiting till it's job done

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I had a code that looks like below

```
fun main() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        doA()
        //call api with Flow as the return type
    }
}
suspend fun doA() {
    viewModelScope.async { doB() }.await()
}
suspend fun doB() {
    //Do logic here, eventually will call line below
    viewModelScope.launch { doC() }
}
suspend fun doC() {
    //call api with Flow as the return type
}
```

What I want to achieve here is to make the `doA()` wait till it's done and after that continue to the function below it, which is the call API function. But when I try to run, the `doA()` not wait until everything finishes on that side. The debug quite help me and I found that when the `doB()` being run and reach the `doC()` which in the new scope, the program continues to the next line after the `doA()` in `main()`.

Is there's something I missing? Why the code doesn't work like what I want? I kind a new in Coroutine to say. And yes, I run the code in the Android environment. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me too Beginner. As per my LIMITED UNDERSTANDING, "async" should be used for running "parallel" jobs and wait for "future results"

For getting the jobs done "sequentially", instead "launch" and "join" should be used. Plz check [Waiting for a job](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#waiting-for-a-job)

Regarding the doA() finishing while doB() is running, its because in doB(), a NEW COROUTINE is launched and it immediately returns, hence the Execution continues with the Next Line in doA(). To make doA() wait, add "join" in doB() while launching the Coroutine

```
fun main() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        doA()
        //call api with Flow as the return type
    }
}
suspend fun doA() {
    //viewModelScope.async { doB() }.await()

    // Replace with "launch" and "join"
    viewModelScope.launch{ doB() }.join()
}
suspend fun doB() {
    //Do logic here, eventually will call line below
    //viewModelScope.launch { doC() }

    // Add join() to make it wait 
    viewModelScope.launch { doC() }.join()
}
suspend fun doC() {
    //call api with Flow as the return type
}
```

But if you prefer to keep using "async", then just add "join" in doB()

```
suspend fun doB() {
    //Do logic here, eventually will call line below
    //viewModelScope.launch { doC() }

    // Add join() to make it wait
    viewModelScope.launch { doC() }.join()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reference, I guess I missed that part when reading the doc. it makes sense to me though, I'll try it then

Comment: this should be the right answer, I tried and work as I expected

Answer (score 1):

For `doB()` and `doC()` you're creating new coroutine to run, so it doesn't run in same coroutine as `doA()`. So, technically doA() has completed its execution. To make `doA()` wait, you have to run doB() and doC() in same coroutine.

```
suspend fun doA() {
    doB()
}
suspend fun doB() {
    //Do logic here, eventually will call line below
   doC()
}
suspend fun doC() {
    //call api with Flow as the return type
}
```

Also, do not use `async-await` if you're using `await` immediately after `async` like `viewModelScope.async { doB() }.await()` because it is same as `launch`.

Comment: so, actually, I don't need to use `await()` in my code? also, you mentioned that when I using `await()` like `viewModelScope.async { doB() }.await()` it's the same using `launch` if I use the `await()` like

`val a = viewModelScope.async { doB() } 
a.await()`

does it still work like `launch`?

Comment: Yes you don't need to use  `async-await` here.  Async is used to do parallel operation and await is used to return the result from the coroutine which in ur case isn't required. Immediately calling await will wait for the Coroutine to finish which doesn't make sense in parallel processing.

Comment: okay, it's clear now. thank you for your answer, I'll try it soon